# Клиент-браузерное взаимодействие. сервер node js не возвращает ответ

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, сервер, браузер

Есть сервер. На порте 8000. localhost.

```js
let server = new http.Server(function (request, response) {
   const { headers, method, url } = request;
   let body = [];
   request.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
   }).on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
   }).on('end', () => {
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

      response.on('error', (err) => {
         console.error(err);
      });
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Connection': 'close',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
      });
      const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };

      if (request.url == '/') {
         console.log(`/ --- ${body}`);
         response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
      } else if (request.url == '/data') {
         console.log(`/data --- ${body}`);
         console.log(response);
         response.write(body);
      }
      response.end();
   });
});
```

Мне нужно что бы он возвращал ответ в браузер, после POST запроса пользователя. И менял содержимое html в браузере.
Я делаю такой POST запрос. И ожидаю что сервер вернёт изменённый responseBody в котором теперь лежит тело запроса, а именно фрагмент вёрстки. Но в браузере body пуст.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S Если тут возвращать просто строку, а не что то динамически изменяемое. она выводится.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ИТОГ: body(payload) приходит на сервер, но не возвращается в DOM браузера.

Comment: сделайте console.log(body) до body = Buffer.concat(body).toString(); и console.log(body) после - что там?

Comment: https://www.postman.com/downloads/
тестируйте сервер - этим приложением!!!

Comment: console.log(`BEFORE -- ${body}`)
body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
console.log(`AFTER -- ${body}`)

BEFORE -- 
AFTER -- 
BEFORE -- 
AFTER -- 
BEFORE -- 
<div class="card _3yellow">
...

Comment: в общем что в AFTER - вы не написали